# My realm file is growing continuously until the app will no longer launch

Tags: ios, swift3, realm

I have an application using RealmSwift on iOS that stores a small amount of data. The data is updated via CloudKit push notifications every ~5minutes or so.

It works except my Realm file continuously grows forever until the application no longer has enough memory to launch.

I managed to work around it slightly by using the "writeCopy" function to compact the realm at launch - this mostly works if the app is stopped semi-frequently so that has a chance to run, but if this does not happen and the app continues to update the data from push notifications in the background for a couple of days, the database will end up too large and compacting it takes *ages*, or it just crashes trying.

I tried reading the "file size" section in the FAQ's but I don't think I fully understand the rules that cause the size to grow. It mentions keeping "old realms" open - does that mean instances of Realm e.g. "let realm = try! Realm()" or does it really mean any open object?

If its the latter then that is annoying as I use notifications on result sets while in the background to determine when to update a complication on a companion watch app.

I really like realm and I want to stick with it but I feel like my somewhat unusual use case (long running app that frequently updates in the background) might mean that I cannot use it.

Edit:

Background updates are happening as a result of the 'didReceiveRemoteNotification' app delegate callback, like this:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    let dict = userInfo as! [String: NSObject]

    let notification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: dict)

    if notification.notificationType == .query {

        let notification = notification as! CKQueryNotification

        if let recordID = notification.recordID {

            let requestOperation = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: [recordID])
            requestOperation.fetchRecordsCompletionBlock = { records, error in

                if let error = error {
                    os_log("Error fetching record: %@", log: Logger.default, type: .error, String(describing: error))
                } else {

                    autoreleasepool {
                        let realm = try! Realm()

                        try! realm.write {
                            records?.forEach { (key, record) in
                                switch record.recordType {
                                case "Freeway":
                                    let dict = RealmFreeway.dictionary(from: record)
                                    realm.create(RealmFreeway.self, value: dict, update: true)

                                case "Segment":
                                    let dict = RealmSegment.dictionary(from: record)
                                    realm.create(RealmSegment.self, value: dict, update: true)

                                default:
                                    os_log("Unknown record type: %@", log: Logger.default, type: .error, record.recordType)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase.add(requestOperation)
        }

    }

    completionHandler(.newData)
}
```

And the watch complication is updated via RxSwift like so:

```
 Observable.combineLatest(watchViewModel.freewayName.asObservable(), watchViewModel.startName.asObservable(), watchViewModel.endName.asObservable(), watchViewModel.travelTime.asObservable(), watchViewModel.color.asObservable(), watchViewModel.direction.asObservable()) {
        freewayName, startName, endName, travelTime, color, direction -> [String:Any] in

        guard let freewayName = freewayName,
            let startName = startName,
            let endName = endName,
        let direction = direction else {
                return [String:Any]()
        }

        let watchData:[String:Any] = [
            "freewayName": freewayName,
            "startName": startName,
            "endName": endName,
            "travelTime": travelTime,
            "color": color.htmlRGBColor,
            "direction": direction,
            "transfers": session.remainingComplicationUserInfoTransfers
        ]

        return watchData
    }
    .filter { $0.keys.count > 0 }
    .throttle(2.0, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .subscribe( onNext: { watchData in

        let MIN_DURATION = 24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0 / 50.0 // 50 guaranteed updates per day...
        var timeSinceLastUpdate = MIN_DURATION
        let now = Date()

        if let lastUpdated = self.lastComplicationUpdate {
            timeSinceLastUpdate = now.timeIntervalSince(lastUpdated)
        }

        // Should we use a complication update or an application context update?
        let complicationUpdate = timeSinceLastUpdate >= MIN_DURATION

        // Send the data via the appropriate method.
        if complicationUpdate {
            session.transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo(watchData)
        } else {
            try? session.updateApplicationContext(watchData)
        }

        self.lastComplicationUpdate = now
    })
    .addDisposableTo(bag)
```

Comment: Do you open explicit autoreleasepool around the background thread Realm? Do you do your updates in a single transaction per update?

Comment: Wow, this is a very interesting implementation of Realm! You're on the right track; Realm uses read-locked copies of the data to guarantee that any objects accessing any Realm data at a given moment don't have the data changed from under them on the fly. As a result, if you're explicitly retaining certain Realm accessors (ie 'pinning' specific versions of the data), that would cause the data to be copied and the file size to increase. Can you please update your question to elaborate how you're using Realm to perform this backgrounding update, and how the changes are forwarded to the Watch?

Comment: If all of your logic is on the main thread, Realm automatically updates the versions on each runloop iteration. However, if your app is being backgrounded by iOS at the time, I'm not sure if that means the runloop is properly running at the time. In that case, one thing you could potentially try is calling `refresh()` on the `Realm` instance that `Results` object belongs to at the start of each update.

Comment: I put some code showing the updates from push notifications, and the complication update code. I am thinking that you could be onto something with the runloop not happening while the application is in the background. It's also possible that I am doing something terribly wrong with RxSwift. This app is kind of an experiment for me to play with both Realm + RxSwift as I don't usually use either.

Comment: Thinking about it more - is it just a matter of me needing to call 'refresh' in any of my RxSwift things that are retaining realm objects?

Comment: Also it'd be great if there was some kind of debug thing to print out how many versions are currently still around?

Comment: Sorry for the delay! I showed the sample code to some colleagues (including the creator of RxRealm). Their opinion was your code might be overkill at the moment; it would appear you're creating a separate `Observable` for every property change (When one for all of them would suffice). You might be able to simplify the code a lot here. As for exposing version counting, that's not a bad idea! Feel free to post a feature request on the Realm Cocoa GitHub.

Comment: But yeah, for tracking this issue in general, it might be more appropriate to take it to the Realm Cocoa GitHub account anyway.